# how to fetch count within bookshelf withRelated method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to get the like count value. Its returning an array i just want to know if there is a way to get the count of the array

```
router.get('/uploads', (req, res) => {
  Image.query((image) => {
    image.orderBy('img_url', 'DESC');
    image.limit(10);

    // if you want to include the user with the image, you would use the withRelated
    // comments.user gets the user within the comments array
  })
    .fetchAll({
      withRelated: [
        'user',
        {
          comments: (qb) => {
            qb.orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
          },
        },
        'comments.user',
       {
         likes: (qb) => {
          // how to get count for likes model its returning an array, i just want
          // count value
         }
       }
      ],
    })
    .then(images => res.status(200).json(images.toJSON()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding bookshelf-eloquent, and added `withCount`

now the router looks like this

```
router.get('/uploads', (req, res) => {
  Image.query((image) => {
    image.orderBy('img_url', 'DESC');
    image.limit(10);

    // if you want to include the user with the image, you would use the withRelated
    // comments.user gets the user within the comments array
  })
    .withCount('likes as likeCount')
    .fetchAll({
      withRelated: [
        'user',
        {
          comments: (qb) => {
            qb.orderBy('created_at', 'ASC');
          },
        },
        'comments.user',

      ],
    })
    .then(images => res.status(200).json(images.toJSON()));
});
```